# IndentationError: expected an indented block, Python 3,6

Tags: python

I am trying to run code that is not in github but is giving error (IndentationError: allowed an indent block)

```
from imageai.Prediction import ImagePrediction
import os
execution_path = os.getcwd()
prediction = ImagePrediction()
prediction.setModelTypeAsResNet()
prediction.setModelPath( execution_path + "\resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5")
prediction.loadModel()$


predictions, percentage_probabilities = prediction.predictImage("C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\1.jpg", 
result_count=5)
for index in range(len(predictions)):
print(predictions[index] , " : " , percentage_probabilities[index])
```

File "C:\Users...", line 12
    print(predictions[index] , " : " , percentage_probabilities[index])
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]

Comment: The error message is clear: inside the for loop the code should be indented

Comment: Can you give us any tips?

Comment: Add 4 spaces at the beginning of the line in the error

Answer (score 0):

You just need to indent the final line of code. Indentation matters in python, it's required syntax in for loops.

```
from imageai.Prediction import ImagePrediction
import os
execution_path = os.getcwd()
prediction = ImagePrediction()
prediction.setModelTypeAsResNet()
prediction.setModelPath( execution_path + "\resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5")
prediction.loadModel()$


predictions, percentage_probabilities = prediction.predictImage("C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\1.jpg", 
result_count=5)
for index in range(len(predictions)):
    print(predictions[index] , " : " , percentage_probabilities[index])
```